# IOS/Xcode: Save Web Service Feed into Core Data

Tags: ios, xcode, web-services, core-data

I have a web app and want to download data from a web service to core data for display in my IOS app.  The ultimate goal is to be able to work on the iOS app off line and later synch up with website (like Facebook) but for now I just am trying to store web service feed to core data and display.  While I realize there are libraries to help, I want to do it natively for first iteration.  Am using http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London,uk as json feed.

Is following is right way to go about it?

Create data model in IOS with same attribute names as variable names in Json response

In main view controller header (vc.h) add NSMutable Array property to hold data and outlet properties for json fields wired to storyboard

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *weatherData;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *temp;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *humidity;
```

In VC source, synthesize properties and in viewDidLoad use NSSession to download data

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];

//1
    NSString *dataUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London,uk];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:dataUrl];

    // 2
    NSURLSessionDataTask *downloadTask = [[NSURLSession sharedSession]
    dataTaskWithURL:url completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {

      // could add error checking here.
// 3
    [downloadTask setTaskDescription:@"weatherDownload"];
    [downloadTask resume];

      // 4: Handle response here
      [self processResponseUsingData:data];
  }];       
}
#pragma mark - Private

// Helper method
- (void)processResponseUsingData:(NSData*)data {
  NSError *parseJsonError = nil;

  NSDictionary *jsonDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data
                                                           options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&parseJsonError];
  if (!parseJsonError) {
    NSLog(@"json data = %@", jsonDict);
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            self.temp.text = jsonDict[@“temp”];
            self.humidity.text = jsonDict[@“humidity”];
        });
  }
}
```

//Save object in Core Data..I don't know how to do this

//Create method using NSFetchedResults controller to pull data from core data and display in table view

Thanks for any comments suggestions.  I have searched far and wide for a good start to finish way to do this can't find a good tutorial or simple account of steps to take.  Everything I've found is either very simple or has lots of dependencies on libraries and therefore very complicated.

Comment: `//Save Object in Core Data` this is done by creating instances of your Core Data Entity and then calling save operation on your managed object context. You might need to be careful about duplicate records though. I see that libraries like Overcoat, Mantle have a "unique" key property which helps the library know which JSON property is the unique key (usually the entity ID).

Answer (score 0):

Another neat way is to do as described in this post: [Pull Website Data Easily iOS](http://www.instructables.com/id/Pull-website-data-easily-on-iOS)

I don't know if this is exactly what you're looking for, but you can later save the array into core data, or just display it as is.